# Debian PHP extension installed but still "missing"

Tags: php, debian

I'm trying to install [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) on my Debian server.

As per the instructions, I've installed `libzmq-dev` with aptitude, and now I'm trying to install the [PHP bindings](http://zeromq.org/bindings:php). Here I managed to install `pecl`, and installed `zmq-beta`. I edited my `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` config to include the extension.

After restarting Apache, my `phpinfo()` shows that ZMQ is enabled.

In one of my projects, I use composer to pull in some PHP packages, one of which called [React](http://reactphp.org/). However I'm given the error message:

> react/zmq v0.2.0 requires ext-zmq * -> the requested PHP extension zmq is missing from your system.

My `extension_dir` is pointing to `/usr/lib/php5/20100525` from my php info, I'm not sure if this is correct.

Anyone got any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I ran `php -m` and the extension wasn't there. Running `php -i` shows the config being loaded from `/etc/php5/apache2/cli/php.ini`. Updated that and it worked.